# Vertical space around theorems

Tags: spacing, theorems

I'm working in a document that has double-spacing (yuck!), and I want to establish some standards in order to make the thing look "presentable".

Currently, the only environment that has an automatic cushion of vertical space is the proof environment.  I would like for the theorems to have the same effect.  In other words, I want a little bit of extra space (say, 1em) between my theorems and the surrounding text.  Here is a minimal example of the code which establishes the spacing.

```
\oddsidemargin 0.25in
\evensidemargin 0.25in
\textheight 612\p@   
\textwidth 6.0in
\footskip 0.5in
\topmargin -12\p@
\headheight 1.5ex
\headsep 24\p@
\parindent 30\p@
\itemsep 0\p@        % keeps spacing within lists consistent
\parsep 0\p@         % keeps spacing within lists consistent
\parskip 0\p@        % keeps spacing b/t pars consistent
\topsep 0\p@         % consistent spacing b/t lists & paragraphs
\partopsep 0\p@      % consistent spacing b/t lists & paragraphs
\topskip 0\p@        % keeps top margin consistent
\textfloatsep 25\p@  % proper spacing for floats
\intextsep 25\p@     % proper spacing for floats

\clubpenalty= 10000           % no orphans allowed
\widowpenalty= 10000          % no widows allowed
\displaywidowpenalty= 10000   % no widows allowed in "displayed" text
\def\myskip{\vskip 9\p@}
\def\stretchv@l{1.66}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\stretchv@l} % double spacing
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
```

I did not write this code, and I would like to know what I should add/edit in order to get the desired results.  I tried to manually add space around the theorem environments, but it seems to cause more problems than not.  By the way, I'm using the report document class.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but `\topskip=0pt` is probably a bad idea. Generally, you want the baselines of the top line per page to be aligned, not the top of the top line.

Comment: instead of the code you've posted, can you post a minimal document using just the packages that you need to show the problem (`utathesis` and `amsthm`?) with a proof and a theorem to show what the problem is.  I think this can be solved, but I would need a test document to play with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using one of the AMS document classes (amsart or amsbook) or saying `\usepackage{amsthm}`, you can define a new theoremstyle, two parameters of which are the skip above the theorem and the skip below the theorem.  For example, I like my theorems to use slanted type in the body instead of italics, and so I use the following:

```
\newtheoremstyle{slplain}% name
  {.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip\@minus.2\baselineskip}% Space above
  {.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip\@minus.2\baselineskip}% Space below
  {\slshape}% Body font
  {}%Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}%  Thm head font
  {.}%       Punctuation after thm head
  { }%      Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
  {}%       Thm head spec


\theoremstyle{slplain}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}  % Numbered with the equation counter
\newtheorem{cor}[equation]{Corollary}     
\newtheorem{lem}[equation]{Lemma}         
\newtheorem{prop}[equation]{Proposition}
```

Almost all of the parameters I used for that `\newtheoremstyle` command are exactly the ones used for the plain theoremstyle in amsart, except that I changed the body font from `\itshape` to `\slshape`.

As noted in the comments, the second and third parameters to the `\newtheoremstyle` command are the space above and the space below.  You can change those to whatever you like (and even change the `\slshape` that I use back to `\itshape` if that's what you prefer).